# Why eBPF requires two memory copies for look up elememnts?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ebpf

I am reading Linux kernel 5.18 and find out that Linux requires two memory copies for bpf(BPF_LOOKUP_ELEM..) system call. BPF_LOOKUP_ELEM calls map_lookup_elem defined at linux/bpf/syscall.c. In map_lookup_elem, bpf_map_copy_value copies lookuped element to value. And later, copy_to_user copies value to user provieded pointer.

```c
static int map_lookup_elem(union bpf_attr *attr)
{
    void __user *ukey = u64_to_user_ptr(attr->key);
    void __user *uvalue = u64_to_user_ptr(attr->value);
    int ufd = attr->map_fd;
    struct bpf_map *map;
    void *key, *value;
    u32 value_size;
    struct fd f;
    int err;

    if (CHECK_ATTR(BPF_MAP_LOOKUP_ELEM))
        return -EINVAL;

    if (attr->flags & ~BPF_F_LOCK)
        return -EINVAL;

    f = fdget(ufd);
    map = __bpf_map_get(f);
    if (IS_ERR(map))
        return PTR_ERR(map);
    if (!(map_get_sys_perms(map, f) & FMODE_CAN_READ)) {
        err = -EPERM;
        goto err_put;
    }

    if ((attr->flags & BPF_F_LOCK) &&
        !map_value_has_spin_lock(map)) {
        err = -EINVAL;
        goto err_put;
    }

    key = __bpf_copy_key(ukey, map->key_size);
    if (IS_ERR(key)) {
        err = PTR_ERR(key);
        goto err_put;
    }

    value_size = bpf_map_value_size(map);

    err = -ENOMEM;
    value = kvmalloc(value_size, GFP_USER | __GFP_NOWARN);
    if (!value)
        goto free_key;

    if (map->map_type == BPF_MAP_TYPE_BLOOM_FILTER) {
        if (copy_from_user(value, uvalue, value_size))
            err = -EFAULT;
        else
            err = bpf_map_copy_value(map, key, value, attr->flags);
        goto free_value;
    }

    err = bpf_map_copy_value(map, key, value, attr->flags);
    if (err)
        goto free_value;

    err = -EFAULT;
    if (copy_to_user(uvalue, value, value_size) != 0)
        goto free_value;

    err = 0;

free_value:
    kvfree(value);
free_key:
    kvfree(key);
err_put:
    fdput(f);
    return err;
}
```

1. I cannot understand why eBPF requires kernel and userlevel copy for lookup elements. It can be changed to shared memory between kernel and userspace memory I think. For example, Kernel makes mapping structure and pass the element location to fd to userspace.
2. I cannot understand why map_lookup_elem ***first*** copies the element value to ***value*** and copies the ***value*** to ***uvalue***? Isn't it ok just copy ptr from map to uvale once? Why kernel tries to first kernel ptr to value and value to user space?

Comment: `bpf_map_copy_value` looks like it does a lot more than simply copy memory...

Comment: I think `bpf_map_copy_value` eventually copies the pointer from `ptr = map->ops->map_lookup_elem(map, key)` by `copy_map_value`. Why `bpf_map_copy_value` copies the kernel space memory ptr to value and `map_lookup_elem` copies the value to uvalue? Isn't it redundant?

Comment: Perhaps it is more expensive to pin user pages into kernel address space than to do the copy through an intermediate buffer in kernel memory, especially when copying small amounts of memory.

Comment: Personally, I think, I cannot agree with this. I thought shared memory between kernel and user will be faster than any other methods because they use hardware based isolation(MMU). I think this maybe related with concurrency problem. Because, if ebpf uses shared memory, cause lock cannot be used with ebpf, concurrency problem may occur.